# WooCommerce Product Bundles - Cart Quantity

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Configuration:

WordPress 4.1
The Events Calendar PRO 3.9
The Events Calendar: WooCommerce Tickets 3.9
WooCommerce 2.2.11
WooCommerce Product Bundles 4.6.2
For an Events website, selling the following tickets:

Adult $25
Child $5
Infant $0
Family $55 (Consists of up 1-2 x Adult, 1-3 Child)
The Family ticket is configured as a WooCommerce Bundled Product, with the bundled products being Adult and Child. Adult is set to a quantity of 2 and Child is set to a quantity of 3

When the Family bundled product is added to the cart, the number of items reported as being in the cart is 6. This is made up of the 1 x Family parent product and the 2 x Adult and 3 x Child children products.

The desired outcome here should be for the cart to report 5 items - 2 x Adult and 3 x Child. In other words, ignore the parent product from the product count.

My question: what is required in order to get WooCommerce to ignore the parent product of a Product Bundle when calculating the number of items in the cart?

Answer (score 3):

I believe that a Bundle in per-product pricing mode will automatically count the number of bundled items. When in "bundle" mode the number of items is assumed to be equal to the parent.

This count tweak is achieved in the Bundles' cart class... so I think it could be disabled via:

```
function so_28359520_remove_bundles_counting(){
    global $woocommerce_bundles;
    remove_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_contents_count',  array( $woocommerce_bundles->display, 'woo_bundles_cart_contents_count' ) );
}
add_action( 'init', 'so_28359520_remove_bundles_counting' );
```

**Edit:** I've revised the code above because it seems that Bundles is using a global variable to access the plugin's main class. *Additionally*, I think that `woocommerce_loaded` fires before the theme is loaded, so that wasn't likely to work ever. I've changed to the `init` hook.

**Edit 2:** Bundles *will* skip counting on the parent item *if* that item is set to use per-product shipping calculations. But if that isn't applicable then you need to disable the Bundles filtering and apply your own:

```
function so_28359520_cart_contents_count( $count ) {

    $cart = WC()->cart->get_cart();

    $subtract = 0;

    foreach ( $cart as $key => $value ) {

        if ( isset( $value[ 'stamp' ] ) && ! isset( $value[ 'bundled_by' ] ) ) {
            $subtract += $value[ 'quantity' ];
        }
    }

    return $count - $subtract;

}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_contents_count',  'so_28359520_cart_contents_count' );
```

Comment: I added your code to my child theme's functions.php file but it made no difference. The comments associated with this function state:

"Filters the reported number of cart items depending on pricing strategy: per-item price: container is subtracted, static price: items are subtracted."

Using a static price so cart count should 1 as child items are subtracted.  I wondered if the filter was actually being applied so I changed the function to return the cart count +10. No change to the cart count so to me this says that the bundled cart count filter is not running.

Any ideas where to from here?

Comment: Of course, I removed your script from functions.php before testing if the filter was running.

Comment: I revised my code because it was never going to run from `functions.php` (and am now correctly accessing the Bundles class) and now one of my bundles with static pricing is showing 3 items in the cart.

Comment: Still no joy after your edit, but hours of testing and I have been able to find a solution, but it involved modifying a core function 'calculate_totals' in 'class-wc-cart.php'. I just need to find out how I can override this function so that I don't have to make changes to core files...

Comment: I'm confused because `calculate_totals()` calculates the total price of the items in the cart. Didn't you want to change the display of the quantity of items in the cart?

Comment: Within this function is a line: `$this->cart_contents_count  += $values['quantity'];` which is manipulating the quantity of items in the cart. My mod involved adding a check to see if the current item was the parent of a bundle and if it was to skip adding it to the `this->cart_contents_count`. By doing this I was able to get the desired cart count.

Comment: Ok, I missed that. But still, `$this->cart_contents_count` is "retrieved" via the cart method  `get_cart_contents_count()`... which runs the count through `woocommerce_cart_contents_count`.. which is the filter that Bundles is using to tweak the quantity counts and the filter that I've disabled in my code.

Comment: I just re-read your question and am reminded that you are trying to get 6 cart items to show as 5 by not counting the parent bundle container? Bundles seems to skip counting the parent items if `per_product_shipping` is active on that product. If that isn't appropriate for you (assuming not since you are selling tickets) then I believe you will need to disable Bundles' filter (As above) and write your own filter... essentially moving what you've discovered in the cart class its own filter function. .

Comment: I tried that, and have tried your filter, but the cart count doesn't change.  I know it should, but it doesn't :(  I have added an answer with the code I have used to achieve the desired result.  Thanks heaps for your help.

Comment: Do you have some kind of caching happening? Because you have something else at play as this definitely changes the cart count for me.

Comment: I wish it was that easy and caching was the problem, but it isn't.  Not sure what else is at play but obviously there is something.  Anyway, the solution in my answer is providing the desired result without any modifications to the core so I am happy that I can now move forward with the rest of the site.  Thanks again @helgatheviking

Comment: I've been working on a issue of similiar kind, I was wondering if you may have an answer to it: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/292999/wc-product-bundles-exclude-a-bundle-itself-from-reporting

Answer (score 1):

With heaps of help from @helgatheviking I have been able to come up with the following solution in my functions.php:

```
function cit_update_cart_count() {
    global $woocommerce;
    $count = 0;
    $cart = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
    foreach ($cart as $key => $value) {
        if (!isset($value['bundled_items'])) {
            $count += $value['quantity'];
        }
    }
    $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count = $count;
}
add_action('init','cit_update_cart_count',10);
```

Comment: This seems like exactly the solution I need for a similar problem. However, when adding to my functions.php I can't open my backend - a server error is returned. Has anything changed since then?

Answer (score -1):

You can use the same function in early posts that is written here

```
  function so_28359520_cart_contents_count( $count ) {

    $cart = WC()->cart->get_cart();

    $subtract = 0;

    foreach ( $cart as $key => $value ) {

        if ( isset( $value[ 'stamp' ] ) && ! isset( $value[ 'bundled_by' ] ) ) {
            $subtract += $value[ 'quantity' ];
        }
    }

    return $count - $subtract;

}
```

But you must use it inside class-wc-pb-cart.php

and inside construct  add
`add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_contents_count',  'so_28359520_cart_contents_count' );`

That works like a charm , but in my theme I had problem with  WC()->cart->cart_contents_count  in header.php , somehow the filter is not applied on that , but using

```
<?php 
    global $woocommerce;
    // get cart quantity
    $qty = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_contents_count();
?>
```

Inside header.php  the filter is applied and I get the correct count.

Comment: Directly modifying `class-wc-pb-cart.php` is ill-advised.