# WooCommerce Bundles Product - Limiting Cart Quantity

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

My configuration:

WordPress 4.1 ,WooCommerce Product Bundles 4.8.2, Woocommerce 2.2.11

I am selling juices in package of 7. I Have a product page per juice, but I do not sell them individually, I only sell the different packages containing 7 juices each (different combinations). I am using woocommerce bundle to keep track of the stock of each juices.

When my 7 juices package is added to the cart, the number of items reported as being in the cart is 8 (one for the bundle package + one per each of the 7 juices).

I would like the cart to report 1 item and, ignore the bundled subproducts from the product count.

How can I get WooCommerce to ignore the subproducts of a Product Bundle when calculating the number of items in the cart?

I have seen a question on the opposite effect (counting only the sub products) : [WooCommerce Product Bundles - Cart Quantity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28359520/woocommerce-product-bundles-cart-quantity)

But nothing to limit the number of items to the main package products (1 if one package purchased, but it could be more if more packages are purchased simultaneously)

Suggestions welcome !
Thanks

Comment: Unless you have enabled "non-bundled shipping" on your bundle, the default behavior is to only count the container item. You should contact Woo support if you are still having issues.