# Remove bundle item in the cart count woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, count, woocommerce, bundle, cart

I building my ecommerce for sell wine with wordpress 4.2.2 and woocommerce 2.3.11
I bought the "Product Bundle" (v. 4.9.5) plugin for woocommerce.

I already insert this function in my function.php file

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'woocommerce_check_cart_quantities' );
function woocommerce_check_cart_quantities() {
    $multiples = 6;
    $total_products = 0;
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
        $total_products += $values['quantity'];
    }
    if ( ( $total_products % $multiples ) > 0 )
        wc_add_notice( sprintf( __('You need to buy in quantities of %s products', 'woocommerce'), $multiples ), 'error' );
}
```

because I need to sell bottles on multiple of 6.
Now I have this problem with the product bundled, because in the cart also the parent item is counted.
If I create a bundle with 6 bottle, in the cart I have the message "You need to buy in quantities of %s products" because the total count is 7 (6 bottles plus 1 bundle).
I write to woothemes support and I recive this answer:

> By default, Bundle contents are not counted. A Bundle will be counted
>   as one item, no matter how many products it contains.
>
> When using Product Bundles and needed to count the content, you need
>   to use the WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() method to count all
>   the cart items.

------ UPDATE -------

I try to add in my function the code from the answers, so now my function.php look like this:

```
<?php
/**
 * Child-Theme functions and definitions
 */

 // check that cart items quantities totals are in multiples of 6
add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'woocommerce_check_cart_quantities' );
function woocommerce_check_cart_quantities() {
    $multiples = 6;
    $total_products = 0;
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
        $total_products += $values['quantity'];
    }
    if ( ( $total_products % $multiples ) > 0 )
        wc_add_notice( sprintf( __('You need to buy in quantities of %s products', 'woocommerce'), $multiples ), 'error' );
}

function so_28359520_remove_bundles_counting(){
     global $woocommerce_bundles;
     remove_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_contents_count',  array( $woocommerce_bundles->display, 'woo_bundles_cart_contents_count' ) );
}
add_action( 'init', 'so_28359520_remove_bundles_counting' );


function so_28359520_cart_contents_count( $count ) {
    $cart = WC()->cart->get_cart();
    $subtract = 0;
    foreach ( $cart as $key => $value ) {
        if ( isset( $value[ 'stamp' ] ) && ! isset( $value[ 'bundled_by' ] ) ) {
            $subtract += $value[ 'quantity' ];
        }
    }
    return $count - $subtract;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_contents_count',  'so_28359520_cart_contents_count' );

?>
```

but nothing happen. I also try a fresh wordpress and woocommerce installation with default theme (twenty thirteen and also twnty fifteen) for test if there is some javascript in the theme that interfering and change the quantity, but the result is the same.
If I have 1 bundles with 6 bottles I get the message from the first function.

Comment: What PHP error do you get?

Comment: with the function cit_update_cart_count() I get
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function get_cart() on a non-object in ..\wp-content\themes\Wine-child\functions.php on line 20
so I discard that function

Comment: Well that means that `WC()->cart` isn't an object, most likely because the `init` hook happens before the cart is initialized. Probably for the best to discard that function.

Answer (score 1):

I already answered this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28362731/383847). You need to disable Bundle's function and write your own to skip counting the bundle containers.

```
function so_28359520_remove_bundles_counting(){
     global $woocommerce_bundles;
     remove_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_contents_count',  array( $woocommerce_bundles->display, 'woo_bundles_cart_contents_count' ) );
}
add_action( 'init', 'so_28359520_remove_bundles_counting' );


function so_28359520_cart_contents_count( $count ) {

    $cart = WC()->cart->get_cart();

    $subtract = 0;

    foreach ( $cart as $key => $value ) {

        if ( isset( $value[ 'stamp' ] ) && ! isset( $value[ 'bundled_by' ] ) ) {
            $subtract += $value[ 'quantity' ];
        }
    }

    return $count - $subtract;

}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_contents_count',  'so_28359520_cart_contents_count' );
```

One thing to note, is that Javascript could be updating the count in your menu/widgets and not taking this in to account for some reason. However, when I "view source" I am getting the desired counts (ie: a bundle of 6 bottles is showing a count of 6).

Or as an alternative, you could modify your counting function to not count the bundle container. Untested:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'woocommerce_check_cart_quantities' );
function woocommerce_check_cart_quantities() {
    $multiples = 6;
    $total_products = 0;
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
        if ( isset( $value[ 'stamp' ] ) && ! isset( $value[ 'bundled_by' ] ) ) {
            continue; // skip the bundle container
        } else {
            $total_products += $values['quantity'];
        }
    }
    if ( ( $total_products % $multiples ) > 0 )
        wc_add_notice( sprintf( __('You need to buy in quantities of %s products', 'woocommerce'), $multiples ), 'error' );
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I try both function, but nothing change. Always error message "You need to buy in quantities of %s products" shown also if I have 6 bottles inside the bundle.
I don't use priced per product, because I put a new price for all bundle.

Comment: You tried to disable the Bundles filter while simultaneously adding your own via `so_28359520_cart_contents_count` ?

Comment: Well, I try to add both parts of code in my function.php file.
I write up (like a new answer) the code I have now in my function.php file.
I'm sorry for my poor understanding of php coding, but I thought these kind of options (bundle) were native inside woocommerce.

Comment: I realized an error in my code (since I found that I have essentially answered this question once already). There is the possibility of some theme Javascript interfering and changing the quantity... I am seeing this in my Storefront test theme, but the source code has the desired quantity. ` I thought these kind of options (bundle)were native inside woocommerce ` not sure what you mean here, but WooCommerce is intentionally modular. Not everyone needs "bundles".

Comment: First of all I'm really really grateful for your help and your time!
I edited the answer with my function.php and update with some new information of my test that I did.

Comment: Review my code... I've since discovered that `WC_Bundles` is not a function, but a class. You need to access its functions via the global `$woocommerce_bundles`.

Comment: Ok I tried your new code. (I update my question with the last code).
In my main website I get a php error:
`PHP Warning:  call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'so_disable_bundles_cart_contents_count' not found or invalid function name in D:\inetpub\vhosts\anticacantina.legsolution.net\httpdocs\wp-includes\plugin.php on line 496`
With the test area (clean wordpress with twenty thriteen and fifteen) there is no error, but still nothing happen. Always the boundle is counted like 1 item.
I really don't know what I do wrong or what don't work.

Comment: Well that just means that `so_disable_bundles_cart_contents_count` doesn't exist even though it has been added to a hook. That's because of a copy/paste fail and it should have said `so_28359520_remove_bundles_counting` to match the function's actual title. You must have `WP_DEBUG` enabled on your live site, but not on the other. It's definitely helpful to have one while working. Sorry for all the copy/paste errors.

Comment: Oh no problem about the copy/paste error, thank you for your help!
I used your last code, but nothing change. I get always the message if I have a bundle with 6 products.
If this can help you, the website is http://anticacantina.legsolution.net/prodotto/prova/ (page product of one bundle).

Comment: Ok, I finally got a chance to test this. I'm still making copy/paste errors. Le sigh. Anyway, `$woocommerce_bundles->cart` should have been `$woocommerce_bundles->display` since the filter is in the display filters/functions are in the display class of the plugin and accessed through the display class property. I've finally confirmed that it is working in the Storefront theme.

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry I feel like I abuse of your help! I try the new code, but nothing change!
I don't understand why for you work but for me no. I try with many browser, clear cache and change theme (for see if some javascript interfering with the function), but it's look the same.

Comment: Well a good bunch of that was me being sloppy. But now I am pretty sure this works. You said you checked with a default theme? How are you testing the count? I've been relying on the cart widget.  http://tinyurl.com/pk3dadd

Comment: I link 2 screenshots to show what happen to me.  [Screenshot 1](http://imagizer.imageshack.us/a/img661/113/RNgq2v.jpg)  [Screenshot 2](http://imagizer.imageshack.us/a/img537/1706/DVCeHO.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I was having issues with this until I realised I needed to use WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() rather than WC()->cart->cart_contents_count

Just thought I'd put this here in case anyone else was pulling their hair out...